# Search for messages in Google Chat Space through Google Vault API

Tags: java, google-vault-api

I'm trying to create a Google Vault Export containing all messages in a Chat Space by querying for a specific Chat Space ID. Unfortunately, creating an export for the following query:

```
 newQuery
    .setDataScope("ALL_DATA")
    .setCorpus("HANGOUTS_CHAT")
    .setStartTime(startDate)
    .setEndTime(endDate)
    .setSearchMethod("ROOM")
    .setHangoutsChatOptions(new HangoutsChatOptions().setIncludeRooms(false))
    .setHangoutsChatInfo(new HangoutsChatInfo().setRoomId(spaceId));
```

produces the following error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
POST https://vault.googleapis.com/v1/matters/<matterID>/exports
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Search method ROOM is not supported for corpus type HANGOUTS_CHAT.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Search method ROOM is not supported for corpus type HANGOUTS_CHAT.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

CorpusType needs to be set to `"HANGOUTS_CHAT"` in order to search in the Google Chat Service. The API also mentions that a `HangoutsChatInfo()` object needs to be passed when the search method is `"ROOM"` (https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/Query#SearchMethod).

Am I missing something or is this a bug? Does anyone know a workaround for this issue, if what I want to accomplish is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is intended behavior as per current design of the API since you will need to provide the corresponding RoomId and it's not possible at the moment.

Someone had a similar problem before and it ended up in a feature request, you can check it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/189250955

Comment: It appears that indeed, as of now HangoutsChatInfo is readonly. Thanks for the clarification!